# School computers disabled chrome://dino. Can you re-enable it using inspect element?

Tags: javascript, inspect-element

As many people can tell, 'admins' of the host, (jdoe@[host]) have disabled the [offline chrome dino game](http://chrome://dino). If I could find this out, all the kids in school would be very happy.

I found out when I started using the inspect element console with the Runner variable, and I saw something interesting. I put in:

```
Runner.prototype
```

Then after that,

```
Runner.prototype.isDisabled
```

I tried `Runner.prototype.isDisabled = false;`, `Runner.prototype.isDisabled(false);`, `Runner.prototype.isDisabled = function () {};` but none of those worked.

Now I'm wondering... Is it possible to re-enable the chrome dino game using inspect element? And I know you can just find an emulator. But c'mon, isn't it more fun on the real site?

Comment: Excellent question!  Looking into it... in the mean time:  https://chromedino.com/

Comment: Have you tried `const r = new Runner(document); r.isDisabled = false; r.startGame();`?

Comment: Also, do you have permissions to edit the registry?  Even, HKEY_CURRENT_USER?  https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AllowDinosaurEasterEgg

Comment: @Brad lol, I'm just going to say if you're in a place where the dino game is blocked you PROBABLY don't want to mess with the Registry

Comment: @Brad with the    const r = new Runner(document); r.isDisabled = false; r.startGame(); it just turns the screen white then when I press space to start, it just shows in the bottom left corner that its blocked.

Comment: Or you could just do work on the school computer, and leave the games at home.

Comment: @dev4life Pretty sure learning/hacking JS (for any purpose) is going to be far more useful than whatever they're teaching.

Comment: @Brad True.  But he should be learning/hacking JS at home.  The school disabled it for a reason, probably because they should be doing work at school, and not playing games.  Just saying.

Comment: @dev4life How fortunate of you to even be able to assume that everyone has a computer at home.  I got my start learning BASIC and a smidge of C++ on a locked down library computer.  Turns out if you open the Encarta '95 Encyclopedia, there is a "notes" feature which launches Wordpad.  From there, you can insert an OLE object.  From that feature, you can launch pretty much anything on the system.  Enough for a curious kid to learn more than I was taught in a classroom all the way through college.  One day, the librarian found out what I was up to... and was overjoyed.

Comment: @dev4life Blanket policies like locking down computers are meant to maintain order and control.  They're to make life easier for teachers.  No doubt if this kid causes a distraction, they'll get in trouble for it.  But, they'll learn something.  Those are the people who push the next generation forward, not the people who fall in line and become the drones of society.

Comment: @Brad I'm not learning it in school I'm just wondering. I mean I do know basic JS and stuff, but just wondering.

Answer (score 3):

The `isDisabled` method doesn't seem to help, it is called inside the constructor to decide whether to setup the game or display a static image, and you would need to override it before the instance is created. (If you did find the appropriate breakpoint, `Runner.prototype.isDisabled = () => false;` should do).

But it seems you can just initialise the game ignoring the `isDisabled` method. The class stores a singleton instance at `Runner._instance`, and you can initialise the game by calling

```
Runner.instance_.loadImages()
```

This might still show the disabled warning when starting the game, to suppress that you should be able to set

```
Runner.classes.SNACKBAR_SHOW = "";
```

Comment: My gosh I think he's got it! He has! Thanks so much. Also, its    instance_ not    _instance.

Comment: @DownTheSewersWeGo hm, I didn't try as I don't know how exactly to reproduce the disabled game

Comment: Maybe there's a way to get the script from a certain site and then put it in that one... Hmmm... That's it!